# Fine precision control in IntervalSlider

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, gui-construction, intervals

I would like to develop a simple slider for exploring a wide range of intervals on the real line.  Is it possible to get the `MinimalSize` of IntervalSlider to work below .001?

```
IntervalSlider[{3, 7}, {0, 10}, ImageSize -> 600,  MinIntervalSize -> .0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"]
```

[image: interval slider]

---

This limitation is not imposed on the HorizontalGauge:

```
HorizontalGauge[42, {0, .000000000000000000001}, ImageSize -> 800, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image: gauge]

---

I may be able to get around this limitation by using a drop down list to set the order of magnitude I wish the gauge to operate in.  But first I want to know about getting around the limited of the control.

Comment: If you drag with Alt pressed it is more sensitive, with Alt+Shift even more. Not sure what you are exactly after, though.

Comment: Basically, I want students to be able to explore a number line by zooming in or out at will. I plan to have multiple Horizontal Gauges on display at once.  But I am still thinking about the functionality, the operations I want students to be able to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there really sufficiently many assignable pixel locations such that you can drag a Controller to such a resolution? Would you be satisfied if the range were small enough that the MinIntervalSize you seek could be rendered?  After all, this will work:

```
IntervalSlider[{.003, .007}, {0., .010}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 MinIntervalSize -> .00000001, Appearance -> "Labeled"]
```

Comment: Good point. I hadn't tried adjusting the interval size!